# Updating of a SharePoint Web URL via Name does not change its lists' urls

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I want to ask is it possible to update a Sharepoint web's lists and all its items' URLs if I call an update on the web's url?  If so, how can I do so?

e.g.

```
web.Name = "newWebName";
web.Update();
```

The above only changed the base web's url.  But the url of its lists remain unchanged.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you wan´t to do, change the name of a SharePoint list, (aka the RootFolder.Name)? If that is the case I am not sure you can actually do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating of the web name will not cause a problem with the lists within the web, hence there was no need to update each individual item's url after changing their web's URL within an AllowUnsafeUpdate.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a SharePoint site to try this, but the `ServerRelativeUrl` property of `SPWeb` can be set, so this is a good candidate for what you are trying to do.